# How to authenticate a ip server in firebase authentication?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I tried using auth in firebase for google sign in. I have done it countless times before only though the preview web server was `localhost:3000` and so I would get a error saying

> This domain localhost:3000 is not authorized to run this operation. go to   -> Auth section -> Sign in method tab.

So i would follow the instructions and enter my authorized preview url as localhost and it would be fine. but this time i'm not using localhost, but i'm using some kind of ip address server and when i try to enter it in firebase it would say "app has to end like a for eg: .com" but my ip server doesn't have a .com or something so firebase doesn't allow it

Also there is nothing wrong with the code i have used it many times before in a localhost 3000 server and it works because firebase auth allows localhost but not ip servers. what should i do?

[image]

Comment: I just tested  and can add an IP address tot he `Authorized domains` of my project without issue (e.g. `192.168.0.7` in the console [here](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/authentication/providers)). Can you show a screenshot of what you did, and the error you get?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen please look at the new edited post.

Comment: `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` is the same. So, if `localhost` works but not `127.0.0.1`, just enter `localhost`

Answer (score -1):

Authorization is for an entire domain, not for a specific port on that domain. So `127.0.0.1` is a valid authorized domain (and is added by default when you create the project), but `127.0.0.1:5500` is not.