# Firebase authentication does not work on 127.0.0.1 but works on localhost

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, localhost

I am using Firebase Authentication in my project, and I've encountered an issue where authentication does not work when using `127.0.0.1` as the host, but it works fine with `localhost`. Is it the case with you? Any insights or suggestions would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <button id="btn1">Log in/Sign up</button>
    <button id="btn2" disabled>Sign Out</button>

    <script type="module">

        import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.9.0/firebase-app.js"
        import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithPopup, signOut} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.9.0/firebase-auth.js"
        const firebaseConfig = {
            // my config
        }

        const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
        const auth = getAuth()
        const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider()

        async function SignIn() {
            await signInWithPopup(auth, provider)

            btn1.disabled = true
            btn2.disabled = false
        }

        async function SignOut() {
            await signOut(auth)

            btn1.disabled = false
            btn2.disabled = true
        }

        btn1.addEventListener('click', SignIn)
        btn2.addEventListener('click', SignOut)

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you add `127.0.0.1` to the list of [authorized domains](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/authentication/settings) in the Firebase console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add `127.0.0.1` to the list of [authorized domains](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/authentication/settings) in the Firebase console.

Also see:

- [Firebase: Error (auth/unauthorized-domain) on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74378824/firebase-error-auth-unauthorized-domain-on-localhost)
- [How to authenticate a ip server in firebase authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69533693/how-to-authenticate-a-ip-server-in-firebase-authentication)